# How to extract months between two dates?

Tags: python, pandas, date

(using python)
I want to extract months between two dates and make them into another list or dataframe. Dates are in different columns, named 'start date' and 'enddate'.

I've tried the following.

```py
df3.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x.df3['startdate'],x.df3['enddate'], freq='MS').strftime("%Y%m"))


columns'startdate' looks like 2010-12-31, 
columns 'enddate' looks like 2011-04-12,
```

I want somethings like this:

```
2010-12
2011-01
2011-02
2011-03
2011-04
```

Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: Provide minimal reproducible code/sample data , and show us your desired output

Comment: How many months are between 2022-02-01 and 2022-03-01?  How about 2022-02-01 and 2022-03-31?  Does the day of the month matter at all, or only the month number?

Comment: I only need the month, ignoring the dates.

Answer (score 0):

Is .dt.month what you are looking for?

```
pd.to_datetime(df['startdate']).dt.month
pd.to_datetime(df['enddate']).dt.month
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. The code below will retrieve the number of days in following month and increment the starting date.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from calendar import monthrange

def months():
    start_date = datetime.strptime("2010-12-31", "%Y-%m-%d")
    end_date = datetime.strptime("2011-04-12", "%Y-%m-%d")  
    
    while start_date < end_date:
        print (start_date.strftime("%Y-%m"))
        days = monthrange(start_date.year, start_date.month + 1 if start_date.month < 12 else 1)[1]
        start_date = start_date + timedelta(days=days)

    print (end_date.strftime("%Y-%m"))

months()
```

Output

```json
2010-12
2011-01
2011-02
2011-03
2011-04
```

Comment: Thanks! But instead of the fixed time in the example "2010-12-31", I need all the dates in the columns to be iterated.

Comment: Wouldn't making the dates arguments to the function and having it return a list accomplish that? Otherwise I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to accomplish.